# How to use the electrum seed password in monero-wallet-cli?

Tags: monero-wallet-cli, mnemonic-seed

I am using more and more commands from the cli wallet and am curious about the following when restoring a wallet:

```
./monero-wallet-cli --generate-new-wallet mytestwallet --password="blahblah" --restore-deterministic-wallet --electrum-seed="$(< mnemonic.txt)"
```

`monero-wallet-cli` will then prompt: `Enter seed encryption passphrase, empty if none:`

1) If I leave it empty, the wallet is generated properly from the specified mnemonic seed.

2) If I enter something a wallet is generated with a different mnemonic seed.

Where in the creation process can I even enter a mnemonic seed password?

Is this legacy for old wallets with 12 word mnemonic + passwords?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create an encrypted seed by running the `encrypted_seed` command in monero-wallet-cli. You will be asked for a password, and the encrypted seed will be displayed. This is an extra line of defense to your seed leaking. Old wallets have 24 words, not 12, and this has nothing to do with them.

Comment: I assume there is no way to do this non-interactively from the `monero-wallet-cli` using an `--arg` of some sort?

Comment: This is correct.